# target specific M3 in ul with css

Tags: html, css

So I have a ul with some li's like this:

```
<ul class="M199 WIDTHBOX1 5ColumnBox">
    <li class="M2">
        <a class="M2" href="about-1561.aspx" target="">About</a>
        <div class="WIDTHBOX2" style="">
            <ul class="M2">
                <li class="M3">
                    <a class="M3" href="site-1571.aspx" target="">Title</a>
```

the ul with class 199 is the only ul with that class.
Can I, in CSS, target the link in M3 for the M3's in this ul alone?

Comment: Something this is? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/9M5ec/)

Comment: This is really quite basic and should be found in a simple internet search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
ul.M199 li.M3 a.M3 {

     /* Your style here */      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Give this a try:

```
.M1999 li a.M3 { color: red; }
```